# UIView as subview orientation frame issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have taken UIView as subview in View Controller

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIView *subview;
```

then I am adding custom UIView class in subview like this ,

```
- (void)showdetail
{
    CGRect frameToset = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.subview.frame.size.width,self.subview.frame.size.height) ;

    customUIViewPaging *demoView = [[customUIViewPaging alloc] initWithFrame:frameToset];

     ... // so on
    [self.subview addSubview:demoView];

}
```

In portrait mode it works perfectly but in landscape I am updating the frame like this,

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
     [self showdetail];
}
```

then after it works perfectly in landscape and portrait then I am pushing a another view from this view and landscaping Pushed view after back coming in this view then frame size not getting perfectly (Subview frame not updating the frames while orientation when coming back from another view)

I have tried to put `needsUpdateConstraints` but it seems not working

```
[self.subview needsUpdateConstraints];
```

[Check this example](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=26832255095869623086)

[image: See this]

Comment: I will recommend you to use only constraints and not to use view frame as you can see "Button" in first view controller is displayed perfectly. Such issue are bound to happen if we mix constraints and frame.

Comment: @aman.sood i didn't get you exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not going to Autolayout direction as you want correct frame when view appears ... If you want correct width than call it `-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{..}`

```
  -(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{ 
       NSLog(@"%f",self.subview.frame.size.width); //here you get correct width
  }
```

now the other problem is you are adding subviews everytime when screen rotates or this method calls .. so better to prevent that by removing previous view...